# Convert if with init-statement (c++17) to c++14

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14

This works only for c++17. Is there a way to convert this to c++14?

```
if (auto user = static_cast<CUser*>(pMover); user && !user->UserState())
        return;
```

Comment: Use 2 statements.

Comment: @prapin and some `{}` to be pedantic

Comment: One way to think of **C++17** is that it is a new, separate, improved language distinct from its predecessor **C++14**.  Most-or-all C++14-isms will work in C++17 (since backwards compatibility is striven to be maintained as much as able), but little-or-none of C++17-isms will work in C++14.

Comment: You probably want `dynamic_cast` here instead

Comment: @TheDreamsWind bold claim without larger context.

Comment: @MarekR just intuition - op checks `user` in the second half of the statement instead of `pMover` somewhere before the statement

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to split the `if` into **2 statements**.
In order to limit the scope of `user` to the `if` statement, you can **enclose it with `{...}`**:

```
{
    auto user = static_cast<CUser*>(pMover);
    if (user && !user->UserState())
        return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it's simple:

```
if (pMover && static_cast<CUser*>(pMover)->IsRecordBookOptIn()) return;
```

`static_cast<CUser*>(pMover)` is nullptr **if and only if** `pMover` is nullptr. And in that case, `&&` doesn't evaluate the right-hand side.